# set div visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set visible `valError`. I tried everything but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function ValidateTextBox(elem) {
        if (elem.val() == "") {                
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    function ValidateForm() {
      var a = ValidateTextBox($('[id$=txtBxLangName]'));

      if (a)
          return true;
      else {                                          
          $('#valError').html('Please fill required field');
          $('#valError').show();
          return false;
           }
     } 
</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <div class="alert alert-error" visible="false" id="valError" runat="server">                       
   </div>                         
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtBxLangName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry">
   </asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btnNewAndUpdate" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnNewAndUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm()" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<div class="alert alert-error" visible="false" id="valError" runat="server">
```

should be

```
<div class="alert alert-error" style="display: none" id="valError" runat="server">
```

Then `.show()` will work.

Just for the purpose of others viewing this, the answer below shows what else is required for this solution to work:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBxLangName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" ClientIDMode="Static">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: If so, I believe the visible = false will have a negative effect on .show()

Comment: @VisioN: Irrelevant. The .NET property `visible="false"` will still mean that the element is not being rendered at all, so there will be no way of showing it with jQuery.

Comment: No problem. It's likely the above answer then by @DaveHogan.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Didn't know. This should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

@thedixon answer is correct however you have another issue too. The textbox `txtBxLangName` might not have that ID when .net renders it to the client. Try adding `ClientIDMode` with the value static to ensure that the ID is set to `txtBxLangName`

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBxLangName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry">
   </asp:TextBox>
```

becomes

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBxLangName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" ClientIDMode="Static">
   </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: And, after this, you can then simply do: var a = ValidateTextBox($('#txtBxLangName'));

Comment: +1. Since `#valError` is `runat="server"` it would also need the `ClientIDMode="Static"`, I assume. Both this and @thedixon's fix needs to be applied for the jQuery to work.

Comment: Yep, @baros will need both of these answers for the fix.

Answer (score -1):

It should display with .show, make sure #valError div has some contents in it or set it's width, height and background and try display block.

```
$('#valError').css('display','block');
```